# Why my code generates values equal to "-nan"?

Tags: c, simulation, montecarlo

I need to calculate the mean of the coverages of two types of particles that could be trapped on a square surface. They are particle #1 and particle #2. Such averages are taken after certain number of steps, for example, every 10 Monte Carlo steps, and considering a number of iterations. The coverages mentioned before are defined as

(number of particles trapped in the surface)/(number of total cells).

The steps of the simulation are:

1. Start with the random collision of a particle on a square lattice.
2. We chose particle #1 with a given probability Y and particle #2 with probability 1 — Y. ("Y is determined by the mole fraction of the particle #1 in the gas phase").
3. If the chosen particle is particle #1, we choose a site on the lattice at random. If that site is full the trial ends. Otherwise, we check its four nearest neighbors. If there is particle #2 in one of its neighbors, particle #3 is generated. Otherwise, particle #1 remains trapped on the surface.
4. If the chosen particle is particle #2, we choose a site on the lattice at random. If that site is full the trial ends. Otherwise, we check its four nearest neighbors. If there is particle #1 in one of its neighbors, particle #3 is generated. Otherwise, particle #2 remains trapped on the surface.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>

//define the dimensions of the grid
#define MAX_X 5
#define MAX_Y 5
//define the iterations 
#define ITERATIONS (MAX_Y*MAX_X)
#define Y 0.44

//define the states of a cell in grid`
typedef enum  { S_EMPTY, P1_OCCUPIED, P2_OCCUPIED, S_NONE } gstate;

// help generate random coordinate of the grid
int gridrnd(int max)
{
    return (rand() % max);
}


// generates random coordinates of the grid
int generate_coords(int* j, int* i ) 
{
    if (!i || !j)
        return 1;

    *i = gridrnd(MAX_X);
    *j = gridrnd(MAX_Y);

   // printf("(%d,%d)\n\n", *j, *i);
    return 0;
}

//function to initialize the grid as empty
void grid_init(gstate grid[MAX_Y][MAX_X])
{
    for (int j = 0; j < MAX_Y; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_X; i++) {
            grid[j][i] = S_EMPTY;
        }
    }
}


double Square( double value )
{
    return value * value;
}


double CalcMean( double number[], int steps)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double pMean = 0;

     // calculate mean

    for (int k = 0; k < steps; k++) {
         sum += number[k];
    }
    
    pMean = sum / (double) steps;   // save mean value

    return pMean;
}  
// returns standard deviation

double CalcStdDev( double number[], int steps, double * pMean )
{
    double sum = 0;
    double stddev = 0;
    
    // calculate standard deviation

    sum = 0;   // NOTE: your code is missing this statement.

    for (int k = 0; k < steps; k++) {
        sum += Square( number[k] - *pMean );
    }
    
    stddev = Square( sum / (double) steps );

    return stddev;
}

//Function that locates the four nearest neighbors of the chosen site, considering periodic boundary conditions
int get_limited_coord(int coord, int coord_max){
    if (coord >= 0 && coord < coord_max) {
        return coord;
    } else if (coord >= coord_max) {
        return coord - coord_max;
    } else {
        return coord + coord_max;
    }
}

    //Function that prints individually the "right" neighbor of the chosen site
    gstate rightneighbor(int x, int y, int *rx, int *ry){
        *ry = get_limited_coord(y, MAX_Y);
        *rx = get_limited_coord(x+1, MAX_X);
        //printf("right neighbor = (%d,%d)\n\n",*ry,*rx);
        return 0;   
    }



int main(){
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    int rx, ry, lx, ly, ux, uy, dx, dy;
    gstate grid[MAX_Y][MAX_X];
    double particle1 = 0, particle2 = 0, particle3 = 0; // counters for the number of particle1 and particle2
    double availcells = MAX_X * MAX_Y; //first we initialize with all the cells of the matrix available
    double fullcells = 0;
    int rounds = 0;
    double N = 1.0*sizeof(grid)/sizeof(grid[0][0]); //number of the total sites in the matrix
    float r;
    double cover1 = 0.0, cover2 = 0.0, created3 = 0.0, sumacov = 0.0, covera = 0.0;
    double average1 = 0.0, average2 = 0.0, average3 = 0.0, averagea = 0.0; //we define the average of the coverages of particle 1 and particle 2   
    double std1 = 0.0, std2 = 0.0, std3=0.0;
    int MCSTEPS = 100;
    double num_1[MCSTEPS];
    double num_2[MCSTEPS];
    double num_3[MCSTEPS];
    double num_a[MCSTEPS];
    double sum_1=0.0, sum_2=0.0, sum_3=0.0, sum_a=0.0; //sum of the coverages of both particle 1 and 2. useful to calculate the average of the coverages

    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    
    // Initialize grid to be S_EMPTY
    grid_init(grid);

    sum_1=0.0;
    sum_2=0.0; 
    sum_3=0.0;
    sum_a=0.0;                  
    for(int time = 0; time < MCSTEPS; time++ ) {
        for(int iter = 0; iter < ITERATIONS; iter++){
            //LOCATE AN ENTRY OF THE MATRIX RANDOMLY
            generate_coords(&j, &i);

            //EVALUATE THE CHOOSEN SITE
            switch (grid[j][i])
            {
                case S_EMPTY:
                    //printf("IT'S S_EMPTY, LET'S FILL IT WITH A PARTICLE. FIRST LET'S GENERATE TO DECIDE IFIT WILL BE TRAPPED\n\n");
                            
                    r = rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
                            
                    if(r <= Y){//The particle #1 is chosen  
                        //printf("r = %lf is less than Y = %lf. We choose the particle #1\n\n", r, Y);
                        rightneighbor(i, j, &rx, &ry);

                        if(grid[ry][rx]==P2_OCCUPIED){
                            grid[ry][rx] = S_EMPTY;
                            particle3++;
                            particle2--;
                            fullcells--;
                            availcells++;
                        } 
                      
                        else{ 
                            grid[j][i] = P1_OCCUPIED;
                            particle1++;
                            availcells--;
                            fullcells++;  
                        }   
                    }
                    else{//The particle #2 is chosen
                        printf("r = %lf is greater than Y = %lf. We choose the particle #2\n\n", r, Y);

                        rightneighbor(i, j, &rx, &ry);

                        if(grid[ry][rx]==P1_OCCUPIED){
                            grid[ry][rx] = S_EMPTY;
                            particle3++;
                            particle1--;
                            fullcells--;
                            availcells++;
                        } 
                    
                        else{ 
                            grid[j][i] = P2_OCCUPIED;
                            particle2++;
                            availcells--;
                            fullcells++;  
                        }           
                    }  

                    break;        
                            
                case P1_OCCUPIED:
                    //printf("IT'S OCCUPIED WITH THE PARTICLE #1. PLEASE, GENERATE ANOTHER SITE ON THE SURFACE\n\n");
                    break;

                case P2_OCCUPIED:
                    //printf("IT'S OCCUPIED WITH THE PARTICLE #2. PLEASE, GENERATE ANOTHER SITE ON THE SURFACE\n\n");
                     break;             
            }  

            cover1 = particle1/N;
            cover2 = particle2/N;
            created3 = particle3/N;
            covera = availcells/N;
        }    
        printf("cover1 = %lf    cover2 = %lf    sumacov = %lf     created3 = %lf    covera = %lf\n\n", cover1,cover2,cover1+cover2, created3, covera);
        
        num_1[time] += cover1;
        num_2[time] += cover2;
        num_3[time] += created3;
        num_a[time] += covera;
    } 

    average1 = CalcMean(num_1, MCSTEPS);
    std1 = CalcStdDev( num_1, MCSTEPS, &average1);
    average2 = CalcMean(num_2, MCSTEPS);
    std2 = CalcStdDev( num_2, MCSTEPS, &average2);
    average3 = CalcMean(num_3, MCSTEPS);
    std3 = CalcStdDev( num_3, MCSTEPS, &average3);

    printf("#particle1 = %lf\n\n", particle1);//total of particle1 adsorbed
    printf("#particle2 = %lf\n\n", particle2);//total of particle2 adsorbed
    printf("#particle3 = %lf\n\n", particle3);//total of particle3 adsorbed
    printf("#availcells = %lf\n\n",availcells);
    printf("#fullcells = %lf\n\n",fullcells); 
    printf("average1 = %lf      average2 = %lf       average3 = %lf      std1 = %lf         std2 = %lf        std3 = %lf      Y = %lf\n\n",average1, average2,average3, std1, std2, std3, Y);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I get for the averages results like
`average1 = -nan,   average2 = -nan,   average3 = -nan,  std1 = -nan,   std2 = -nan,  std3 = -nan`

But I can't see why I'am getting those results. What does it mean "-nan"?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: NaN means Not a Number. Maybe you divided by zero somewhere? Also try making a minimal example.

Comment: There is no need for such a large program to ask this question. For debugging questions, you should provide a [mre], with emphasis on the **minimal**. You should reduce your code to the minimum amount needed to reproduce the problem. You should do preliminary debugging before posting on Stack Overflow. Insert code in various places to test your results for NaNs. (If the condition `x != x` is true, `x` is a NaN.) When a NaN is found, the print a message and abort the program. Use that to locate where the first NaN occurs, repeating as needed to narrow it down.

Comment: Also suppress `srand((unsigned)time(0));`. Change it to `srand(1)` to create reproducible results. (That makes it reproducible for you, using your C implementation. It may not be reproducible for people using other C implementations, since `rand` is not fully standardized. You should replace `rand` with a specific implementation to make the problem reproducible for other people. There is a sample portable implementation of `rand` and `srand` in the C standard.)

Comment: Thanks. I just edited my code and left a shorter one. This time I'm only checking the right neighbor, still having the same problem for the averages

Answer (score 0):

The code never initializes the elements of `num_1`, `num_2`, `num_3`, or `num_a`.

Comment: Thank you, I did it, but still having the same problem.

Comment: I also edited the original code and left a shorter version that reproduce the same error. This time I'm not checking all the neighbors, only the right one.

Comment: @Auyk: The new code you have posted in the question does not initialize the elements of `num_1`, `num_2`, `num_3`, or `num_a`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I just initialized those arrays using memset. It seems it's working now. Still checking....Sorry again. I'll come back in case I have another question. Thank you :)